# Loading feeds dynamically by selecting a feed from a list of links

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I am making a news app, and I am using a jQuery plugin called zRSSFeed. The plugin comes with a feature to change the RSS feed displayed by selecting a news source from a dropdown, which would alter the feed showing in the result Div (see example [here](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_menu.html)).

Source code :

```
<script src="http://jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setRSSFeed('#menu');
    $('#menu').change(function() {
      setRSSFeed(this)
    });
    function setRSSFeed(obj) {
      var feedurl = $('option:selected', obj).val();
      if (feedurl) {
        $('#result').rssfeed(feedurl);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<select id="menu">    
  <optionvalue="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">News</option>
  <option value="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC </option>
  <option value="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

My problem is that instead of changing the feed displayed by selecting a newsource from the dropdown, I would love to change them by selecting a link (href) with a specified new source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this

```
<select id="menu">    
  <optionvalue="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">News</option>
  <option value="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC </option>
  <option value="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</option>
</select>
```

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //setting default feed
    setRSSFeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews');
    });
    function setRSSFeed(feedurl) {
       if (feedurl) {
             $('#result').rssfeed(feedurl);
                 }
              }
          });
</script>

    <a href="#" onclick="setRSSFeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews');">News</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="setRSSFeed('http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list');">BBC</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="setRSSFeed('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss');">CNN News</a>
```

Comment: its not working...am a newbie please write everything out clearly THANKS!!